# Realm + Object Mapper + SwityJSON

Tags: ios, swift, realm, swifty-json

I need help in mapping my object

Realm Model: https://gist.github.com/n1tesh/7d6c6e155285dd6b39c8edba76f6eba5

This is how I'm doing

```
    // write request result to realm database
    let entries = json["data"]
    realm.beginWrite()
        let entry: ChatGroups = Mapper<ChatGroups>().map(JSONObject: entries)!
        realm.add(entry, update: true)

    do {
        try realm.commitWrite()
    } catch {

    }
```

JSON Response: https://gist.github.com/n1tesh/bf84cbd930f8c76b340f21723a217ebe

But i'm getting error
`fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

Please help me out with what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: How do you get the json variable and what is its type?

Comment: @DávidPásztor Its of type JSON. I'm using SwiftyJSON.                 if let value = response.result.value {
                    let json = JSON(value)
                    callback(true, json, nil)
                }

Comment: @Nitesh i saw something different in your mapping, updated_by and member are arrays, so you have to use var members = List<GroupMember>() for example. Try to use RealmOptional<Bool>() instead of Bool. For the list you need to do a transform to work see this: https://gist.github.com/Jerrot/fe233a94c5427a4ec29b

Comment: @Nitesh one more thing, try to use if let statement. Don't do this let entry: ChatGroups = Mapper<ChatGroups>().map(JSONObject: entries)!, do this 
if let entry: ChatGroups = Mapper<ChatGroups>().map(JSONObject: entries) {}.

Comment: @JoséNeto Thanks but still facing the issue.

Comment: @Nitesh can you show me how it is with the changes?

Comment: @JoséNeto https://gist.github.com/n1tesh/7d6c6e155285dd6b39c8edba76f6eba5/edit Also one thing I was going completely wrong is entries  should be like this             let entries = json["data"].dictionaryObject. Now I'm getting all data except members

Comment: @Nitesh Can't see t he code. Did you use ListTransform?

Comment: @JoséNeto YEs. https://gist.github.com/n1tesh/7d6c6e155285dd6b39c8edba76f6eba5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a class to transform Array to List, because the Realm doesn't accept arrays.

```
import ObjectMapper
import RealmSwift

public class ListTransform<T:RealmSwift.Object> : TransformType where T:Mappable {
    public typealias Object = List<T>
    public typealias JSON = [AnyObject]

    let mapper = Mapper<T>()

    public init(){}

    public func transformFromJSON(_ value: Any?) -> Object? {
        let results = List<T>()
        if let value = value as? [AnyObject] {
            for json in value {
                if let obj = mapper.map(JSONObject: json) {
                    results.append(obj)
                }
            }
        }
        return results
    }

    public func transformToJSON(_ value: Object?) -> JSON? {
        var results = [AnyObject]()
        if let value = value {
            for obj in value {
                let json = mapper.toJSON(obj)
                results.append(json as AnyObject)
            }
        }
        return results
    }
}
```

Then in your ChatGroups class you have to call the Transform function to make the transformation, make this change:

```
updated_by              <- map["updated_by"]
members                 <- map["member"]
```

to this:

```
updated_by              <- (map["updated_by"], ListTransform<QuorgUser>())
members                 <- (map["member"], ListTransform<GroupMember>())
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem. Appreciate your efforts in digging hard to solve this.

Comment: @Nitesh no problem mate! :)

Answer (score 0):

In your `ChatGroup` class you have declared

```
dynamic var image: String = ""
```

but in your response your are getting null in image key of JSON response.

You need to convert your declaration to:

```
dynamic var image: String? = nil
```